# visual studio 2010 searching using textbox

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

im getting error when i put letter in textbox search what should i do?

```
 Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txtsearch.TextChanged
        Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM tblsample WHERE fName LIKE '%" & Txtsearch.Text & "%' "

        Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

        Dim SqlAdpter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

        Dim TABLE As New DataTable

        With SqlCommand
            .CommandText = SqlQuery
            .Connection = conn

        End With

        With SqlAdpter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(TABLE)
        End With

        lvw.Items.Clear()
        For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
            With lvw
                .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("uid"))
                With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("fname"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("lname"))
                    .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("me"))
                End With
            End With
        Next
    End Sub
End Class

Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txtsearch.TextChanged
    Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM tblsample WHERE fName LIKE '%" & Txtsearch.Text & "%' "

    Dim SqlCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

    Dim SqlAdpter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    Dim TABLE As New DataTable

    With SqlCommand
        .CommandText = SqlQuery
        .Connection = conn

    End With

    With SqlAdpter
        .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
        .Fill(TABLE)
    End With

    lvw.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With lvw
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("uid"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("fname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("lname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("me"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Saying _getting error_ without saying what is that error is not very helpful. Please add the error message received.

Comment: sorry this is the error ----->>.Fill(TABLE) The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.

Comment: This is pretty basic. When you want to connect to a database you use an instance of a DbConnection derived class. This class needs a fundamental property that helps locate the database. It is called ConnectionString. The variable con has no ConnectionString, and without that property you could not connect to anything. [See this site for examples of ConnectionStrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com)

Comment: i already connect it into the database ..my form is for add,edit,delete but search box is my problem .when i run the program every thing work exept for textboxsearch  im getting error in fill table

Answer (score 0):

The error is clear. The `conn` global variable has no `ConnectionString` set. Why do you keep a global connection object? Instead keep the string with the `ConnectionString` property as global or read it everytime from your config file. Then build the SqlConnection on the spot and destroy immediately after you have finished to use it.

ADO.NET implements the Connection Pooling infrastructure and keeping a global object for the connection is a bad practice.

```
Private Sub txtSearch_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Txtsearch.TextChanged

   Dim SqlQuery As String = "SELECT * FROM tblsample " & _ 
                            "WHERE fName LIKE @search"
   Dim cnString as String = GetConnectionString()
   Using conn = new SqlConnection(cnString)    
   Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, conn)
   Using SqlAdpter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter()
        Dim TABLE As New DataTable
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@search", _
            SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255).Value = "%" & Txtsearch.Text & "%"
        With SqlAdpter
            .SelectCommand = SqlCommand
            .Fill(TABLE)
        End With
   End Using
   End Using
   End Using

    lvw.Items.Clear()
    For i = 0 To TABLE.Rows.Count - 1
        With lvw
            .Items.Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("uid"))
            With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("fname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("lname"))
                .Add(TABLE.Rows(i)("me"))
            End With
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

In the example above, all the variables that work with the database are local, are created locally and destroyed before exiting from the sub. The only part that remain to be defined is the call to GetConnectionString. This should be a function in your code that returns the ConnectionString to use for the SqlConnection and you could prepare it in many ways (a fixed text (not recommended), reading your web.Config or App.Config (recommended))